# Reset Polymer paper-input-container value and label

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm having trouble resetting the label inside a paper-input-container after submitting a form. The form is a simple login form. If a user logs in, out, and back in again without a page refresh (from the browser), the label appears to be stuck as if there were a value in the input.

Here's an image to show the difference:

[image: login forms]

Here's the form inside the element:

```
<form is="iron-form">

    <paper-input-container id="email_container">
        <paper-input-error>E-mail or Password is incorrect</paper-input-error>
        <label>E-Mail Address</label>
        <input is="iron-input" id="email" on-blur="validateEmail" value="{{emailInput::input}}">
        </paper-input-container>

        <paper-input-container id="password_container">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input is="iron-input" id="password" type="password" value="{{passwordInput::input}}">
        </paper-input-container>

    <paper-button raised dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
    <paper-button raised on-tap="handleCsrf">Login</paper-button>

</form>
```

These two approaches both get the form to the "after login" state the same:

```
//
this.emailInput = null;
this.passwordInput = null;

//
this.emailInput = "";
this.passwordInput = "";
```

I thought this would reset the entire container somehow, but it does nothing:

```
this.$.email_container = null;
this.$.password_container = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

[iron-input](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-input)

> bindValue
>   String
>   Use this property instead of value for two-way data binding.

```
   <paper-input-container id="email_container">
    <paper-input-error>E-mail or Password is incorrect</paper-input-error>
    <label>E-Mail Address</label>
    <input is="iron-input" id="email" on-blur="validateEmail" bind-value="{{emailInput::input}}">
    </paper-input-container>

    <paper-input-container id="password_container">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input is="iron-input" id="password" type="password" bind-value="{{passwordInput::input}}">
    </paper-input-container>
```

With `bindValue` apparently both `this.emailInput = null` and `this.set('emailInput, null)` do the trick.

Comment: That seems to be for custom inputs like `<ssn-input>`. Mine is just a regular input as iron-input. It's almost verbatim from the polymer docs.

Comment: Tried this is doesn't solve the issue. also i believe the syntax is this.$.emailInput = null

Comment: 'bind-value` property implements two way binding. `value` property only notifies due to user input.  Then access the two way binding via `event.target.bindValue` inside `on-tap` event handler, or `this.email.bindValue` (using id `email`).  Relevant doc [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-input).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the first form didn't work (I'm using a paper-input, not iron-input, and it worked there), it's possible the problem is somewhere in the code not shown. But something else to try is directly setting the value:

```
this.$.email.value = null; // where 'email' is the ID of the iron-input
```

I'm not entirely sure how this will interact with `bind-value`, but the docs do say

> `iron-input` adds the `bind-value` property that mirrors the `value`
>   property

Answer (score -1):

You can reset a complete `iron-form` by calling the `reset()` method:

```
document.getElementById('idOfForm').reset();
```